# Unable to install Mesa opengl for off-screen rendering on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, mesa

I am trying to install Mesa opengl for off-screen rendering on ubuntu command-line based environment (no X window). I have failed to install due to an error: `configure: error: egl requires --enable-dri`

Command i am using to configure: `configure --enable-osmesa --disable-driglx-direct --disable-dri --with-gallium-drivers=swrast`

Steps I followed:

1. Downloaded Mesa from <https://mesa.freedesktop.org/archive/11.1.4/>
2. Installed/upgraded python, flex, mako, bison
3. However, i did not install dri2proto, libdrm, Xorg server as it is mentioned in section 1.2 of <http://www.mesa3d.org/install.html> that these options need to be installed when targetting "DRI and hardware acceleration" which i am not...i guess as i am after off-screen only.
4. After this I issue config command I listed above.

Is there anything wrong that I am doing?

Comment: Why don't you use Mesa from Ubuntu's package repository? I think its package is called libgl1-mesa-dev.

Answer (score 0):

Mesa's cross-platform EGL implementation [doesn't exist any more](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/commit/?id=5564c361b5cc1f5ec4be3622d7f9be601e3c268a).  All that's left is the DRI one.  Which, as you've noticed, requires DRI.

If you don't need EGL toss in a `--disable-egl` on your `configure` command line.